# Python: cannot import name x for importing module

Tags: python, python-import

** EDIT: Copy-pasting my actual file to ease confusion. The code snippet below is in a file named train_fm.py:

```
def eval_fm(x,b,w,V):
  # evaluate a degree 2 FM. x is p X B
  # V is p x k

  # some python code that computes yhat
  return(yhat);
```

Now in my main file: I say the following

```
from train_fm import eval_fm
```

and I get the  error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name f1
```

When I type

```
from train_fm import train_fm
```

I do not get an error.

OLD QUESTION BELOW :

```
def train_fm(x,y,lb,lw,lv,k,a,b,w,V):
 # some code
  yhat = eval_fm(x,b,w,V);
  # OUTPUTS
  return(b,w,V);
```

I have a file called f2.py, where I define 2 functions (note that one of the functions has the same name as the file)

```
def f1():
    some stuff;
    return(stuff)

def f2():
    more stuff;
    y = f1();
    return(y)
```

In my main file, I do

```
from aaa import f1
from aaa import f2
```

but when I run the first of the 2 commands above, I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name f1
```

Any idea what is causing this? The second function gets imported fine.

Comment: is it spelled correctly when you import it?

Comment: If the file is called `f2.py`, what is `aaa`? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: You are not importing `f2.py` and we don't know what `aaa` is. Maybe you can show us your file structure. But you've got to respond to the questions asked.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my post.